# Unable to use Keycloak's Hostname SPI

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

It appears I am misunderstanding how SPIs are supposed to work with the Keycloak XML config. Based on my (very quick) skim of the Keycloak source it appears any usage of `<spi name=xx><provider` results in custom jar files being unable to provide alternative implementations of that SPI. This seems unlikely.

I'm attempting to use Keycloak's [Hostname SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_hostname). I've built my ProviderFactory and my Provider, and I can see from debugging keycloak that my `META-INF/services/org.keycloak.urls.HostnameProviderFactory` file is being loaded. I also see that my factory class is being loaded into the JVM and the no-args constructor is called.

However, the factory is never shown on the list of available factories, and directly calling it using `session.getKeycloakSessionFactory().getProviderFactory(HostnameProvider.class, "my-id");` returns a null.

From tracing Keycloak it seems that my confusion has something to do with the fact that the config XML file I am using already defines `<spi name="hostname"><provider name="default" ...`.

In `ProviderManager#load(Spi,String)` I see my custom factory being loaded, but because it does not have a providerId of `default` it is just ignored. This is called by `DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory#loadFactories(ProviderManager)`, which has a large if-else that mainly differs in how it handles a provider being found in the config file. If a provider is found, it only loads SPI implementations with the same name as the one found in the config file, else it loads all SPI implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make your custom provider the default provider in standalone.xml:

```
<spi name="hostname">
  <default-provider>my-id</default-provider>
  <provider name="my-id" enabled="true">
    <properties>
       ...
    </properties>
  </provider>
</spi>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused why. None of the other SPIs behave like this, you can easily provide a different one and reference it dynamically

Comment: Some plugins (e.g. HostnameSpi, UserCacheSpi) are treated like a singleton for the whole Keycloak server. Others (e.g. AuthenticatorSpi, UserStorageSpi) may have multiple instances of different providers. These instances usually can be selected or created via the admin console)